# Order of pattern matching evaluation in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Take the two similar looking functions:

```
foo :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
foo [x,y] | x == y = True
foo _ = False

bar :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
bar _ = False
bar [x,y] | x == y = True

main = do
print $ foo [1,1]
print $ bar [1,1]
```

When compiled with ghc, the result is predictably:

`True`

`False`

Because it seems the order in which it evaluates different pattern groups goes from the top down. My question is whether this behavior is defined in the language itself or just by the compiler? For example, if I use a different compiler could I get the opposite result? I want to know if it's predictable or ambiguous like in C/C++

Comment: Compared to C, haskell semantics is essentially completely predictable. The evaluation order, instead, is not predictable. This might seem a contradiction, but when evaluating `a + b` in Haskell it does not matter which one between `a,b` is evaluated first, since there are no side effects (unlike C), so the result will be the same. The Haskell report only mandates a predictable result, and does not mandate a specific evaluation order.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is defined in the language itself. [Subsection 4.4.3.1 of the Haskell Report 2010](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-840004.4.3.1) specifies that the clauses in a function definition are equivalent to a case expression. Case expressions, in turn, have their alternatives matched in order. Quoting [section 3.13 of the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-460003.13):

> A case expression is evaluated by pattern matching the expression *e* against the individual alternatives. The alternatives are tried sequentially, from top to bottom.